# JSF Scope when using <ui:include/> inside a form

Tags: jsf, primefaces, scope

I want to scope a backing bean, such that it is newly constructed, every time a dialog is opened.
This is the dialog:

```
<h:form id="myForm">

            <p:dialog header="Title" id="someDialog" widgetVar="someDialog" modal="true"
                    resizable="false" closable="true">
                <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/myInclude.xhtml"/>
            </p:dialog>
 </h:form>
```

Then my include.xhtml:

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<p:outputPanel id="dataPanel">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <p:outputLabel value="Bar"/>
        <p:separator/>
        <p:commandButton value="Test" action="#{myController.test}"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:outputPanel>
</ui:composition>
```

This include should use the myController bean:

```
@Component
@Scope("view")
public class MyController {
 
     private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyController .class);

     @PostConstruct
     private void postConstruct(){
         LOGGER.info("post construct");
     }

     @PreDestroy
     private void preDestroy(){
         LOGGER.info("pre destroy");
     }

     public void test(){
         LOGGER.info("test");
         PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("PF('someDialog').hide()");
     }
 }
```

When I click a button that opens `someDialog`, and click `test` for the first time I get the following output:

```
post construct
test
```

The dialog hides as expected, but preDestroy isn't called because it's view-scoped and the view doesn't change. I had a look at the scopes but none seemed to fit my needs. How can I achieve that the Bean is destroyed when the Dialog is hidden? And then once again constructed when the Dialog reopens?

Comment: What makes you think an include has its own view scope? It just results in a component in your view.

Comment: I didn't expect it to work. I knew I would probably need something else.

Comment: You might be looking for https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/components/dialog?id=ajax-behavior-events